# About Grails render's doubts

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I wrote a simple example of filter render, the results are very disappointing, not to understand why there is this situation

who can answer for me .

1.The environment：
Grails Version:2.3.7 , JDK:1.8
2.program file:
My Fiflter:

```
class MyFilterFilters {

def filters = {

    all(controller:'*', action:'*') {

        before = {

            if (!controllerName) return true



            if(!session.user && controllerName !='myRender')

            {

                println "------------------------"

                render view:"/login"

                return false

            }

        }
        after = { Map model ->
        }

        afterView = { Exception e ->
        }
    }
}
```

}

My Controller:

```
class MyRenderController {
def index() {
    render text:"any message!!!"
    return
}
```

}

my login page(login.gsp):

```
This is login page
```

3. test result:
   url:`http://localhost:8080/renderTest/`
   [why???](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TXBE3.png)

Comment: If the site is hosted on your machine (locahost) we won't be able to see it. Can you explain what is happening and what you're expecting to see?

Comment: Your issue is not clear

Answer (score 0):

With your code your login page will also get filtered so it will go in infinite loop.

```
def filters = {
    allExceptIndex(controller:"site",action:"index",invert:true) { // make proper change for controller and index
        before = {
        }
        after = { Map model ->
        }
        afterView = { Exception e ->
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: if (!controllerName) return true